# Can not set title in Navigation bar when click on tabbar item in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I try to create UItabbarcontroller in UIViewcontroller. But when I click on tabbar item (firstview), it shows Navigation bar at top of the root viewcontroller. I set title but it is not shown.

Code create UITabBarcontroller:

```
self.tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

// FirstViewController
First *fvc=[[First alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
fvc.title=@"First";
fvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i.png"];

//SecondViewController
Second *svc=[[Second alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
svc.title=@"Second";
svc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"im.png"];

//ThirdViewController
Third *tvc=[[Third alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
tvc.title=@"Third";
tvc.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];

self.tab.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc, svc, tvc, nil];

[self.view addSubview:self.tab.view];
```

And code in Firstviewcontroller :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    userLogin1 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey :@"textfieldtext"];
    NSLog(@"User login: %@",userLogin1);

    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@",userLogin1]; // it not works

}
```

Please see this image :
[image]
It only show button Back, it not show title. I don't know why.

Comment: USE self.title=NSLocalizedString(@"FIirstViewControllerTitle",nil); in fvc ViewDidLoad..

Answer (score 3):

Set it like this :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    userLogin1 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey :@"textfieldtext"];
    NSLog(@"User login: %@",userLogin1);
//Here
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@",userLogin1]; // it not works

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are adding the `UITabBarController` to a `UINavigationController`, then you need to do the below:

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@",userLogin1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set image or color in your navigation bar then use this code..

```
     // For Background Image
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage 
     imageNamed:@"TitleImage.png"]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     // For Background Color
     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor 
     whiteColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For Navigation Bar Title, Use this code...

```
     self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"FirstViewControllerTitle",nil);

                                     OR

     self.title = @"FirstViewControllerTitle";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `UINavigationController` for each `ViewController` in `UItabbarcontroller`

```
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller_1];
```

and set title for each `ViewController` like this

```
self.title = @"yourTitle";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this

```
[self.tabBarController setTitle:@"Title"];
```